# Node/Express - Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I have been dealing with this problem now for quite a while, and I can't seem to figure out why it's happening.

I'm getting the Error: `Can't set headers after they are sent`.

I was able to track down the offending Function Call via the Stack Trace, which leads me to believe that the error lies within this function:

```
exports.getCardUser = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.user) {
    User.cardUser(req.user.userId, function(responseValue) {
      res.json(200, responseValue);
    });
  } else {
    res.send(401);
  }
};
```

However, if I hit the Endpoint via a regular REST Client, iex: Hitting the API Endpoint in an Isolated Environment, the Error is not being thrown.

Any ideas?

Edit: skypjack's brought me on the right track - Callback was called twice. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean *if I hit the Endpoint via a regular REST CLient*? and what is the alternative that does throw the error?

Comment: I think maybe this isn't the block of code to blame, perhaps a peice of middleware is.

Comment: The most common source of those types of errors is a callback called twice, so you shouldn't track down the offending method, instead try to understand if its callers are all working properly.

Comment: Edited the post for clarification - REST Client: Hitting the Endpoint in an Isolated Environment, instead of it being run as part of the Application.